# ListView with Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, dictionary, listviewitem

Hello I'm looking for a way to use listview with Dictionary.

```
public class ServiceDataObject : IEquatable<ServiceDataObject>
{
   public int ServiceID { get; set; }
   public string ServiceName { get; set; }
   public bool Status { get; set; }
   public string ReccomendedStatus { get; set; }
   public string WhoMade { get; set; }
   public bool Equals(ServiceDataObject other)
   {
       if (other == null) return false;
       return (this.ServiceID.Equals(other.ServiceID));
   }
}
public static Dictionary<int, ServiceDataObject> ServiceData = new Dictionary<int, ServiceDataObject>();
```

This is how my dictionary looks like.

```
lvUsers.ItemsSource = Order_CONTROLS.ServiceData;
```

This is how I assign data to listview
And lvUsers listview:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn>
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Status}" GroupName="{Binding ServiceName}"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn>
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate.Resources>
                          <local:InvertBooleanConverter x:Key="InvertBooleanConverter" />
                      </DataTemplate.Resources>
                      <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}"  GroupName="{Binding ServiceName}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Reccomendation" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReccomendedStatus}" />
         <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ServiceName}" />
     </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
```

Problem is that it does not print data to items only correct, only number of rows are correct, but no data output, can anyone tell what I did wrong and if possible without using LIST(T)?

Comment: Try lvUsers.ItemsSource = Order_CONTROLS.ServiceData.Values; Remember also that Dictionary isn't observable.

Comment: It works. Thank you I wish I could mark your comment as answer.

Comment: Great! I added it as answer. Remember to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set **Values** **Collection** to ItemsSource of the ListView:

```
lvUsers.ItemsSource = Order_CONTROLS.ServiceData.Values;
```

Remember also that **Dictionary isn't Observable** -> I**NotifyCollectionChanged & INotifyPropertyChanged** interfaces aren't implemented.

So if you add a new element to the dictionary, your view will not see this change.

Comment: How to understand that isnt Observable?

Comment: It means that it doesn't implement INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces, so for example, if you add a new element to your dictionary the view won't be notified of this new add.

Comment: That means if data is changed it wont be noticed?

Comment: It means that if you add an element to the dictionary, the view will not see this new element because CollectionChanged event won't fire. If you intend to modify do something like this, Dictionary isn't you best choice.

Comment: Thats not a problem, since this data in listview is for reading. For future use what workaround would be?

Comment: If you wan't you can implement your own Observable Dictionary or use an ObservableCollection for example.